# Mousepad Unresponsive on re-enabling with toggle key

Tags: 12.04, mouse, aspire

The mouse pad does not respond when re-enabled using the toggle keys on Acer Aspire 5738ZG. It responds when restarted from suspend though!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with my Acer laptop. I have a different one now, so I can't remember exactly what the symptoms were, but I know that it wouldn't always wake up properly when it had gone to into 'sleep'. I'd check for a firmware update. They are generally excellent laptops, and this was the only issue I had.

Comment: There is no issues with the firmware, checked it again!